# Customizing Woocommerce Archive Page URL ('/page/')

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Woocommerce archive pages look like this by default:

```
/shop/product-category/page/2
```

But is there a way to change the '/page/' prefix? I would like to use cyrillic naming here.

Comment: So you want to change/translate the language of that specific part? or what is the desired result?

Comment: @Syntax_Error, yes, exactly